# Web sockets and RestAPIs with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I am trying to create a gateway server that works with both rest apis and also web sockets. I have setup the rest api part but I am currently struggling with the ws part. I have the server running on localhost:8181. To configure the web socket I have used the following code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry){
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

}
```

but when trying to connect to the server i keep getting this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8181/ws/info?t=1697111951247' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
abstract-xhr.js:132     GET http://localhost:8181/ws/info?t=1697111951247 net::ERR_FAILED 403 (Forbidden)
```

to connect with the server I am using the following code from a static html page

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8181/ws');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, onConnect, onWebSocketError);
```

I've replaced http://localhost:8080/ws with just /ws then it gives invalid host error
I have even tried setting CORS in Spring using the following code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/ws/*")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8181")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("")
            .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

Still no luck. Any help is appreciated

Comment: had to replace this registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS(); with registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS(); and it worked